# Canvas/Photo - getImageData not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am loading a picture into a canvas; I drawImage(), store getImageData() into a variable for manipulating. I would like to be able to manipulate the data many times for example: add/remove various filters. How can I store the data so that it updates every time I draw the picture with putImageData()?

Basically, I think I am misunderstanding the use of getImageData or using it incorrectly. My thought was that any manipulation that was done to the picture, I could run getImageData and update the variable that contained the information, and use it to "redraw" the picture.

Example:
In the snippet below Lets say I run a function that turn the picture black and white. I have another function that resizes the picture when it is clicked. **When I resize the picture the the black and white filter disappears**. What am I doing wrong to keep the information of the picture?

```
//Read in picture
var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function leDraw(e){
                    imgObj = new Image();
                    picWidth = canvas.width/2;
                    picHeight = canvas.height/2;
                    imgObj.src = e.target.result;
                    newX = 0;
                    newY = 0;
                    ctx.drawImage(imgObj,0,0, picWidth, picHeight);
                    imageData = ctx.getImageData(newX,newY, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    originalCopy = ctx.getImageData(newX,newY, picWidth, picHeight);
                    data = imageData.data;

function resize(val){ Resizes picture

        userPicHeight = document.getElementById("cSelect").value;
        userPicWidth = document.getElementById("cSelect").value;
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, newX, newY, userPicWidth, userPicHeight);
        window['imageData'] = ctx.getImageData(newX,newY, userPicWidth, userPicHeight);
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, newX, newY);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

`imageData` is a snapshot of canvas pixel data. In your case it's the entire canvas's (colored--not B&W) pixel data.

So when you do `.putImageData(imageData...)`  the unaltered snapshow is again displayed on the canvas.

**If you want to rescale a B&W version of your picture:**

1. Draw your color image on a new canvas created with `var memCanvas = document.createElement`. Size the canvas to the image size. The canvas can be left in-memory -- no need to `appendChild` it into the DOM.
2. Apply the filter to the new canvas with `getImageData`, modify pixel data, `putImageData`. Now you have an "image-canvas" that you can later use to resize, etc.
3. Draw the image-Canvas onto the visible canvas: `context.drawImage(memCanvas,0,0)`. Yes, the memCanvas can be an image source for `drawImage`.
4. To scale the B&W version of the image, just clear the canvas, scale the canvas with `context.scale` & then draw the scaled B&W image with `drawImage(memCanvas,0,0)`

If you later want to re-rescale the B&W image, you can do Step#4 again.

**Example code and a Demo using a grayscale filter:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/kingcard.png";
function start(){

    // create a grayscale image-canvas
    var grayImg=makeFilteredImageCanvas(img,grayscaleFilter);
    
    // scale the visible canvas
    ctx.scale(1.25,1.25);
    
    // draw the grayscale imag-canvas on the canvas
    // (the result will be scaled)
    ctx.drawImage(grayImg,0,0);

}

function makeFilteredImageCanvas(img,filter){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    iw=c.width=img.width;
    ih=c.height=img.height;
    cctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    filter(cctx);
    return(c);
}

function grayscaleFilter(context){
    var canvas=context.canvas;
    var w=canvas.width;
    var h=canvas.height;
    var imageData=context.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var data=imageData.data;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
          var gray=data[i]*0.33+data[i+1]*0.5+data[i+2]*0.16;
          data[i]=data[i+1]=data[i+2]=gray;
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Grayscale image scaled up by 25%</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<h4>Original Image:</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/kingcard.png' crossOrigin='anonymous'>
```

Comment: Thank you, this clears some things up for me and gives me some ideas to work with. The one small thing that remains an issue for me is the actual "scaling" in my project will be based on the user's input from a slider. Additionally, the project is like a photo editor, so I the user will be able to click and drag to move the photo around, change and add multiple filters. This example definitely gives me some ideas.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, having a cached filtered image-canvas makes resizing much more efficient because you don't have to refilter each time.